# URL obfuscation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET with MVC4. In a simple controller I wish to use a URL such as

```
www.sitename.com/controller/action/param1/param2/param3
```

Can I do this?

The controller would be `ControllerController` and have a method

```
Action(param1, param2, param3)
```

etc

Comment: You certainly can.  But other than url routes that just take an ID, setting up the specific params like that may be limiting compared to just querystring.  www.sitename.com/controller/action/param1?param2=a&param3=b will bind to your action just as well, and more easily allows you to add &param4=c next month since you don't need to change the routing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just add a route such as:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "MyRoute", url: "{controller}/{action}/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}");
```

If you want it for a specific controller then you can use "hard" names instead of the `{controller}` and `{action}` placeholders.

Make sure you add this before the more specific routes though (i.e. before the "Default" route).

You may also find the [RouteDebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger) on NuGet helpful.